# Function for returning all prime factors of a number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, output, primes, freeze, prime-factoring

I have a predefined function "`primes`" that returns an infinite list of all prime numbers. I wrote the following code for a function "`prime_factors n`" to return all the factors of `n` that are also prime.

```
prime_factors n = [x | x<-primes, n `mod` x == 0]
```

On executing `prime_factors 12` it gives me the correct output `[2,3` but keeps executing after that with no output. Why is this happening and how can I put a stop it?

For reference, here's the entire code segment:

```
primes :: [Integer] 
primes = f [2..] where f (p:xs) = p: f [x | x <- xs, x mod p/=0] f [] = []

prime_factors n = [x | x<-primes, n mod x == 0, x*2 <= n]
```

Comment: 'Primes' returns infinite list! That means prime_factor will keep searching in the infinite list, right?

Comment: ``prime_factors n = [x | x <- primes, n `mod` x == 0]`` is the same as ``filter (\ x -> mod n x == 0) primes`` and since `primes` is an _infinite_ list as you say, the filter goes on for an infinitely i.e. indefinitely long time. that's _why_. as to _how_, you fix this with `takeWhile`: ``prime_factors n = [x | x <- takeWhile (<= n) primes, n `mod` x == 0]``. (answering in the comments since the question is closed).

Answer (score 0):

```
primes :: Int -> [Integer]
primes n = take n $ f [2..]
  where f (p:xs) = p: f [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p/=0]

prime_factors :: Int -> [Integer]
prime_factors n = [x | x<-primes n, n `mod` fromIntegral x == 0]
```

This is not a beautiful solution (am relatively new to Haskell myself), but it stops the program from running indefinitely by using the `take` function to ensure that you never get more entries than a finite number of entries up to `n`, which by definition will be far more than you need because there will always be fewer primes than natural numbers up to a given threshold, i.e., `length [2,3] < length [1,2,3]` etc.

Hopefully, someone else can give you a more elegant solution. But this one works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an error on trying this: q1.hs:8:55: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the second argument of ‘(<)’, namely ‘n / 2’
      In the expression: x < n / 2
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x < n / 2
  |
8 | prime_factors n = [x | x<-primes, n `mod` x == 0, x < n/2]
  |                                                       ^^^

Comment: I had inappropriately used the ```/``` operator; I switched it to a times operator that accomplishes the same function. You can try that one instead.

Comment: This works, but unfortunately, the program does not stop running. Also added x*2 <=n for all results

Comment: Can you post your full code? The problem is likely somewhere other than what you've shown.

Comment: You should edit the question and include it there for everyone to see.

Comment: I've pointed the question at two duplicates that do a good job of explaining the problem and the right solution.